# Change time format in log file

Tags: shell, sed

I have a squid log file in the following format:

```
31/Jul/2014:13:44:52 +0400.701 0 172.16.204.59 TCP_DENIED/407 5232 GET http://vec01.maps.yandex.net/tiles? - NONE/- text/html
```

But the log analyzer needs the time in unix format.

The date command can convert to unix format:

```
date -d "31 Jul 2014 12:51:57 +0400" '+%s'

1406796717
```

But I cannot compose a sed command for changing the format. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Better than after-processing the logfiles would be to configure the time format used in logs in the [squid config](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/LogFormat) so that it produces the correct date/time format.

Comment: I did it. But i need analyze old data.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example use this:

```
$ date -d"$(sed -r 's#^([0-9]{2})/(\w*)/([0-9]{4}):([0-9:]{8}).*#\1 \2 \3 \4#' file)"
Thu Jul 31 13:44:52 CEST 2014
```

Which makes use of this sed:

```
$ sed -r 's#^([0-9]{2})/(\w*)/([0-9]{4}):([0-9:]{8}).*#\1 \2 \3 \4#' file
31 Jul 2014 13:44:52
```

It catches text from start of the line that contains this data: `XX/word/YYYY:ZZZ`, being `ZZZ` a combination of 8 digits and semi colons.

Or more accurate:

```
sed -r 's#^([0-9]{2})/(\w*)/([0-9]{4}):([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}).*#\1 \2 \3 \4#' file
```

Comment: Isn't it better to configure the proper format in squid config?

Comment: It is better, yes. I posted my answer assuming the OP does not have the possibility to change it. In fact, I don't know squid, so I don't know how realistic is my hypothesis :D

Comment: having "business as usual" in an IT company, the co-worker who configured that sits next to him, didn't know about that requirement. Now both are willing to change but it is now "legacy" because of important "things"... you are right! ;)

Comment: How i can use date command for create outpur file with right time format (unix timestamp)?

Comment: @БайХрэй well you can catch the output and put it back in. For example, with: `$ d=$(sed -r 's#^([0-9]{2})/(\w*)/([0-9]{4}):([0-9:]{8}).*#\1 \2 \3 \4#' file)` and then `sed -r "s#^([0-9]{2})/(\w*)/([0-9]{4}):([0-9:]{8})#$d#" file`. Use `sed -i` for in-place editing.

Comment: @hek2mgl ooooh legacy code and legacy configurations. They say that preparation of the environment should last very long, so that good solutions come. Otherwise, all the future will have this handicap. Measure twice, cut once.